# how to define decryption of caeser cipher

Tags: python-3.x, caesar-cipher

Ok So I missed class and am trying to do the work they did in there. One of the problems was fixing a caeser cipher. I believe I have fixed all except for the last part which is of course the part I'm stuck on. This is what I have.

```
#Change to T to lowercase in plaintext
#add : to the end of if statement      
def encrypt(plaintext, alphabet, key):       
        plaintext = plaintext.lower()
        cipherText = ""
        for ch in plaintext:
            idx = alphabet.find(ch)
            if idx >= 0 and idx <= 25:
                cipherText = cipherText + key[idx]
            else:
                cipherText = cipherText + ch
                #add return ciphertext
        return cipherText
#add def to decrypt line
def decrypt(cipherText, alphabet, key):
        plainText = ""
        for ch in cipherText:
            idx = key.find(ch)
            #add and idx <= 25 to if statement
            if idx >= 0 and idx <= 25:
                plaintext = plaintext + alphabet[idx]
            else:
                plaintext = plaintext + ch
        return plaintext
#got rid of def main
#have myCipher = encrypt
# define both myCipher and my plain to the encrypt and decrypt
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
key = "nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm"
plaintext = input("Enter the text you want to encrypt: " )
myCipher = encrypt(plaintext, alphabet, key)
myPlain = decrypt(cipherText,alphabet, key)


print(myCipher)
print("Checking if decryption works: ")
print(myPlain)
```

When I run the code it says cipherText is not defined in

```
myPlain = decrypt(cipherText,alphabet, key)
```

I have tried a few different options but I seem to be going further from fixing it than what I have it as now. So is a way I can define cipherText  in that line or do I have to redo that line and change it to something else?

This is the error I get when I tried to change cipherText as LalolDublin suggested

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\David\Downloads\caeser (2).py", line 32, in <module>
    myPlain = decrypt(myCipher ,alphabet, key)
  File "C:\Users\David\Downloads\caeser (2).py", line 21, in decrypt
    plaintext = plaintext + alphabet[idx]
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'plaintext' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: look closer at how, and where you are returning your ciphered text and the answer will be apparent.

Comment: Ok I am trying to understand what you mean by that. I am looking at it, but its not so apparent to me. My only guess would be that you mean for me to change the mycipher to = decrypt(encrypt) but I tried that and it was not an accepted function either.

Comment: I'll give it a try I don't know python very well but i was directing you the variable names, check the answer Im posting and if it works please accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use cipherText it's a local variable only within that function...

```
myCipher = encrypt(plaintext, alphabet, key)
myPlain = decrypt(myCipher ,alphabet, key)
```

Comment: @LalolnDublin Yes I tried this at one point but ran into another error.

'code' Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\David\Downloads\caeser (2).py", line 32, in <module>
    myPlain = decrypt(myCipher ,alphabet, key)
  File "C:\Users\David\Downloads\caeser (2).py", line 21, in decrypt
    plaintext = plaintext + alphabet[idx]
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'plaintext' referenced before assignment 'code'

Comment: I am sorry i treid to enter that as code so you could see it more clearly and I failed so I'll add it to the OP at the end

Answer (score 0):

Ok as LalolnDublin stated I needed to put myCipher instead of cipherText, he was right but I also needed to change the position of where I entered the code so that it could work properly. This is the finished product if anyone has a similar problem as I did here.

```
key = "nopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm"
plainText = input("Enter the text you want to encrypt: " )
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
def encrypt(plainText, key, alphabet):
        plainText = plainText.lower()
        cipherText = ""
        for ch in plainText:
            idx = alphabet.find(ch)
            if idx >= 0 and idx <= 25:
                cipherText = cipherText + key[idx]
            else:
                cipherText = cipherText + ch
        return cipherText
myCipher = encrypt(plainText, key, alphabet)
def decrypt(myCipher, plainText, alphabet, key):
        plainText = ""
        for ch in myCipher:
            idx = key.find(ch)
            if idx >= 0 and idx <=25:
                plainText = plainText + alphabet[idx]
            else:
                plainText = plainText + ch
        return plainText
myPlain = decrypt(myCipher, plainText, alphabet, key)



print(myCipher)

print("Checking if decryption works: ")

print(myPlain)
```